# Angular ng-pattern only include numbers and hyphens

Tags: angularjs

When using `ng-pattern` on an input, what would the right way to only include numbers and dashes (-).

```
ng-pattern='/^[0-9]+$/',
```

Comment: Have you tried `'/^[\d\-]+$/'`?

Comment: Isn't it more a question about regular expressions than Angular

Answer (score 0):

Just remove ' and replace with "  ng-pattern="/^[\d\-]+$/". And one advice from personal experience: Don't declare pattern in controller. Better declare it in html. Cheers!